# How to approach a respected researcher?

Tags: journals, research

I'm developing a theory that (I think) is pretty good and something new. I'm thinking of contacting a respected researcher (one of the best in the field), mainly because I'm not 100% that this has not been already done (perhaps under another context) or perhaps the theory even isn't new, but equivalent to some other theory. The main reason I am skeptical is that it's a pretty straightforward generalization of a known theory. I see several options:

- write the paper and send it to him asking what does he think about it (and what things can be done additionally)
- write the basic idea and ask if he would like to collaborate
- just try to publish it and see what happens

I like the 1st option, but it might sound like I'm bragging.

Comment: Do you really need to ask one of the most respected resrarchers in the world whether your theory has already been developed in another context? If only there was a website with a vast array of experts from many fields...

Comment: Maybe better for https://academia.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: (voted to close cause in my opinion it belongs better to the Academia Stack Exchange site)

Comment: Regardless if this is off topic or not, if you are a PhD student couldn't you consult with your advisor? If you are not, then you should know by now some people you can consult with.